# Why did SN10 rest at a slight incline after landing?

Tags: rocket-science

Recently when SpaceX's SN10 landed, before it exploded, it sat still on the ground for a few minutes.

It appears to be resting at a slight incline.

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: I would ask on the Space Exploration Stack Exchange. [The landing has been discussed in some detail here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50540/).

Comment: The short answer is no-one knows, but three out of the six legs failed to deploy and the landing was harder than expected, so it's likely one of more of the legs failed.

Comment: Good question; there are some early answers to [Why was the SpaceX Starship SN10 slanted when it landed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50580/12102) in Space SE